# get more data after some given id in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new using firebase and I'd like to make an infinite scroll pagination to my posts.

Suppose I have this post IDS:

```
-M5HMGs3EnBv6O2NSxG
-M5HMGsA3YyW_NJ3fSV
-M5HMGsdfLOOEPPBR_s
-M5HMGsiH9HIZw9DNaz
-M5HMHFYoUX8kNolLrP
-M5HMHFZvDrV27S2hSt
-M5HMHFnrQ_l4mVQ0rX
-M5HMHFoaV8wbexwPCd
-M5HMJQaaFGxF450lJB
-M5HMJQe319R19Cvak6 // THE LAST ONE IN FIRST PAGINATION
-M5HMJQh2gWuah7GSht
-M5HMJQlrcfTTF3fbbI
-M5HMJQo6QT1HwWP2lz
-M5HMJQrIUiZyzhiqK3
-M5HMJQudSkFdvs42D1
-M5HMJRCmbFbxKp1NgA
-M5HMJRFwfo7yN8Is3-
-M5HMJRIsKT3YmoukQ0
-M5HMJRKDTq7XuqtshT
-M5HMJRNRabXbYQUMi6
-M5HMJRS1t9UBzH_3Jh
-M5HMJRXEv6BaPeQPMn
-M5HMJR_bRdxCBy-uma
-M5HMJRdOPBA-SMoMjB
```

So, first I get the first 10 posts till the id `M5HMJQe319R19Cvak6` using this:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('/posts/').limitToFirst(11);
```

it is ok. When I go to the last post my reactjs will call this function again sending the last loaded post ID (the M5HMJQe319R19Cvak6) in variable `pageNumber`.

What I'd like to do is get posts after this last id given to continue the pagination, like so:

```
-M5HMJQh2gWuah7GSht
-M5HMJQlrcfTTF3fbbI
-M5HMJQo6QT1HwWP2lz
-M5HMJQrIUiZyzhiqK3
-M5HMJQudSkFdvs42D1
...
```

I tried to use startAt(ID) but no result has shown:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('/posts/').limitToFirst(11).startAt(pageNumber);
```

any ideas how can I get posts after an id in firebase?

Comment: I think you need 3 variables for that: first n, last of first n and next n that starts after the last of previous n.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database queries consists of two steps:

1. You call one of the `orderBy` methods to order the child nodes on a specific value.
2. You then call one of the filtering methods (`startAt`, `endAt`, `equalTo`) to determine where to start and stop returning data.

Your code does that second step, but fails to do the first step. This means that you're using Firebase's default sort-order, which is by each node's priority. Priorities are a left-over from the days then this API didn't have any better sorting options. These days, you'll always want to call `orderBy...` before filtering.

With that knowledge, your query for getting the second page of results should look something like:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/posts/')
  .orderByKey()
  .startAt("-M5HMJQe319R19Cvak6")
  .limitToFirst(11)
```

I highly recommend calling the `"-M5HMJQe319R19Cvak6"` value something else than `pagenumber` as that variable name makes it seem as if Firebase queries are offset-based, which they aren't.

Comment: thanks a lot! As I wanna show new data first I use endAt and limitToLast instead!